# Netflix questions

Tags: discussion, faq

Should questions about availability of movies on netflix or agreements Netflix has made over movies be allowed?  I don't have anything specific in mind otherwise I'd ask it to get an honest opinion.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with questions about the availability of movies on any format is that this is 'localized' to use the language of stack-exchange, for two reasons:

- Its only of interest to some people (not everyone can even get Netflix)
- Its only for a certain point in time and will certainly go out of date.

Answer (score 1):

If its a specific question about how the Netflix service runs (or any streaming/dvd service including Amazon, Youtube, iTunes, Blockbuster, etc), it should be **off-topic.**

If it is a question about why a certain movie is not available on stream vs DVD for any of these services, <strike>**I don't see a problem.**</strike> Not concerning regional restrictions **are fine**.

Example

- "Why does Sony prevent Netflix from renting out Ponies Are Awesome 7: The Return of Ponystein"  **Fine**
- "Why does Paramount not allow their films in [Country X]" **Off-Topic, burn it with acid**(too localized)

If it is a question about whether a movie is available on [Stream], Netflix and others allows you to [**browse their directory as well as search**](http://www.netflix.com/BrowseSelection) for a title.  So with that available, I believe availability questions should be **Off-Topic** because it shows a lack of research.

Something that must be kept in mind is that Netflix in particular have very different selections between their streaming and DVD service but the search feature I linked will state if an item is available only on DVD/Blu Ray.

Comment: No, a question is not too localized just because it's specific to a country. Please read [Joel's explanation of “too localized”](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/1916). I'm not convinced that the questions belong here, but it's not a matter of being too localized. Too localied would be “why doesn't the rental place down the street carry X”.